# C++ - How to write to files in an Apache module?

Tags: c++, apache, apache2, writetofile, apache-modules

I have the following code, in `C++` (in `Ubuntu 16.04`) for an `Apache HTTP Server module`.

I would like to write some debug to logs (using `std::ofstream`), but I don't see anything. Neither the logs, or the files.

I've also tried to use one of the multiple log routines that apache already has on the `http_log.h`, such as the one below `ap_log_pid`, but I see nothing being written.

How can I write some debug logs to a file, in an `Apache module`?

```
#include <httpd.h>
#include <http_log.h>
#include <http_core.h>
#include <http_protocol.h>
#include <http_request.h>

#include <apr_strings.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

void write_something_to_a_file() // <---- DOESN'T WRITE TO FILE!
{
  std::ofstream myfile;
  myfile.open ("//home//myubuntu//myubuntu//textfile_1.txt");
  myfile << "Writing this to a file.\n";
  myfile.close();
}

static int myserver_handler(request_rec *r)
{
    write_something_to_a_file(); // <-- DOESN'T WORK :(

    ap_log_pid(p, "//home//myubuntu//myubuntu//textfile_2.txt"); //<-- DOESN'T WORK

    return OK;
}

static void register_hooks(apr_pool_t *pool)
{
    ap_hook_handler(myserver_handler, NULL, NULL, APR_HOOK_LAST);
}

module AP_MODULE_DECLARE_DATA   myserver_module =
{
    STANDARD20_MODULE_STUFF,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    register_hooks
};
```

Comment: could be permission issue? did you try different location where apache server has write permission?

Comment: I only have experience with ISAPI but your file writing function should work perfectly so long as the user that your application executes under has permissions to write to the mentioned directory.  I would expect that this default user does NOT have write access due to security concerns.